# Storing IList in Isolated Storage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage, ilist

I have an IList of classes, but when I try to store them in IsolatedStorage it just says the built-in seralizer can't handle it, and neither can JSON.net. I have put the class below, can anyone think of a way to store it?

The error I get is;

> Type 'System.Windows.UIElement' cannot be serialized. Consider marking
>   it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its
>   members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.

```
IList<ScoreWatcher> RecentSessions = new List<ScoreWatcher>();
public class ScoreWatcher
{
    public ScoreWatcher() { }

    public string SessionName = "";
    public DateTime SessionCreationTime;
    public DateTime SessionModificationTime;

    public int Player1Total = 0;
    public int Player1ScoreRollover = 0;
    public int Player2Total = 0;
    public int Player2ScoreRollover = 0;

    public string Player1Name = "";
    public string Player2Name = "";

    public ListBox scoreListBox;

    public string GrabFriendlyGLobal()
    {
        UpdateModificationTime();
        return string.Format("{0}-{1}", Player1Total, Player2Total);
    }

    public void UpdateModificationTime()
    {
        SessionModificationTime = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public void UpdateScoringSystem()
    {
        UpdateModificationTime();

        Player1Total = 0;
        Player1ScoreRollover = 0;
        Player2Total = 0;
        Player2ScoreRollover = 0;


        foreach (Match snookerMatch in matches)
        {
            if (snookerMatch.Player1Score > snookerMatch.Player2Score)
                Player1Total++;
            else if (snookerMatch.Player1Score == snookerMatch.Player2Score)
            {
                Player1Total++;
                Player2Total++;
            }
            else
                Player2Total++;

            // House cleaning
            Player1ScoreRollover += snookerMatch.Player1Score;
            Player2ScoreRollover += snookerMatch.Player2Score;
        }

    }
    public void LoadMatchesIntoListbox()
    {
        UpdateModificationTime();

        scoreListBox.Items.Clear();

        foreach (Match snookerMatch in matches)
            scoreListBox.Items.Add(new UserControls.GameHistoryTile(snookerMatch.GlobalScore, snookerMatch.Player1Score, snookerMatch.Player2Score));
    }

    public List<Match> matches = new List<Match>();
    public class Match
    {
        public int Player1Score = 0;
        public int Player2Score = 0;

        public string GlobalScore = "0-0";
    }
}
```

Comment: You need a concrete class - you can't serialize an interface as far as I know

Comment: After researching on concrete classes, it looks like what I posted is?

Comment: No an interface is a contract for an implementation - it defines behaviour not state - a concrete class is one that provides an implementation. Any interfaces are not serializable (though I assume you are serializing the whole list... not just a single item because ScoreWatcher is concrete - the IList<ScoreWatcher> is not)

Answer (score 1):

You can only serialize concrete classes

Ideally you need to change your implementation to provide a concrete type for the serializer - do you need this to be an IList?

Edit: Ah I see you aren't serializing an interface then - basically you have a reference to a UIElement on your class. You need to specify this to be ignored by the XmlSerializer - are those event handlers handled by a form?

Edit 2: FYI if you want to do this you can use the XmlIgnore attribute or NonSerialized depending on if you are using BinaryFormatter or XmlSerializer to do the serialization

e.g.

```
[XmlIgnore]
public int SomeProperty { get; set; }
```

Comment: I could just use a List. Would that be better?

Comment: Just changed it so that it uses Lists instead. I still get the same error. I updated the first post with the error.

Comment: @TomDwyer, Charleh updated his post.  The problem is that one of your classes has a reference to a UIElement which are not serializable (I'm guessing it's the `ListBox scoreListBox`).

Comment: Good spot chris - probably that's the issue - stick [XmlIgnore] or [NonSerialized] on that and you should be happy (if you are using XmlSerializer or Binary/SoapFormatter respectively)